# Identification Can anyone advise on care of this plant?

Tags: identification, plant-care, leaves, flowers, perennials

Just purchased this perennial, but it did not have any information with it.
My plant identifier states it is Carpet Bee Balm, but because of the red leaves I am unsure. Anyone any other ideas?
[image]

Comment: Good question; if could include a closer illustration of the top & closer illustration of the leaves, size of the leaves, and overall height, could also be helpful. We encourage you to browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!